# Where are temp tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, temporary-files

In SAS, temp tables stored in `WORK`, which locates at the bottom of library list.

In SQL Server, create a temp table like #t1 in `tempdb`. But in the databases list, I cannot find the `tempdb`.

The reason why I want to "see" it is I want to know its variables' data type and other related information.

Comment: It might depend on version, but in SQL 2012 you'll find the tempdb under _System Databases_ and the #t1 would be under _Temporary Tables_ I don't think you can see the structure of the table there though.

Comment: Yea I find it. But as you said, nothing useful information was found there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: tempdb]

You have to expand 'System Databases' to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the following:

```
 exec sp_columns YourTempTableName.
```

That should give you your columns and types.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have security access to that database. Are you sys admin? Or using Sa credentials? There Are four system databases, model, master, tempdb and msdb ... Can you see any of these? If not, you need SQL permission set for your login